# From which email address will php send in mail() function

Tags: php, email

I am making an email form but from which email address is the mail sent?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the mail server is configured, but generally if defaultly configured it will show up as user_executing_php_process@server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from whatever email adress you specify as sender:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

for headers, you can add:

```
$additional_headers.= "From: foo@bar.com";
```

But help yourself and use PHPMailer along with a well configured, dedicated SMTP-Server to send mails: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

(You'll run into lot of issues otherwhise)

Comment: @user3091177 because you can not send "from" a adress you are not ownning. The php mail() function will establish its own connection using the local smtp server (and most likely get blocked due to lack of proper configuration). When you send using a remote smtp, the smtp will append the "from" part automatically, based on the provided authentication. (ps.: it's not generally bad - but only about 0.01% of people wanting to use `mail()` have a well configured local smtp server)

Comment: quick question, what is the difference from "$mail->From = 'from@example.com'" and "$mail->Username = 'user@example.com'"

Comment: @Anwar Username is the name used for authentication (not necessarily an email-adress) with your smtp server. If your inbox serves multiple email-adresses you can specify from which adress to send. For regular EMail Providers they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

PHP sends email from your email address created at hosting. That's your email created at your cPanel.